# How do I implement multiple navmenus?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the *navmenu* feature of Bootstrap.  recently I realized I needed a second one.  since I'm using the slide-in approach (where the z-index of the navmenu is set to 1 and canvas to 2) adding a second slider poses the problem that one obscures the other.  it occurred to me to place the second slider on the right but that doesn't seem to work well... Bootstrap exhibits some funky behaviour when opening it...

so my question: how are multiple navmenus implemented? do I have a single navmenu with multiple divs inside that I have to hide/show? or do I need to hide/show the multiple navmenus?

**edit I**

as a corollary, is there a way to hook myself into the animation that bootstrap provides?  I can set up a click hander on the nabvar item that opens/closes the navmenu to show/hide the right content, but it executes independently of the sliding such that it slides first and then it shows.  what I'd like to do is chain onto the slide such that it shows before the slide and hides after the slide

**edit II**

ah. one other mention: I'm using the *jasny-bootstrap* plugin

Answer (score 0):

looking through the source for Jasny I found that it is possible to hook into the start/end of the show/hide process:

```
$('.navmenu')
    .on('show.bs.offcanvas', function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

and, of course, the other events are available: `shown.bs.offcanvas` and `hide.bs.offcanvas`

**edit I**

after much struggle the above didn't work out so I ended up putting my various pages inside a single slider like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="page1">
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
    </div>
</div>
```

adding an extra parameter to the toggler:

```
<a class="nav-toggle"
    data-toggle="offcanvas"
    data-recalc="false"
    data-target="#slider"
    data-canvas="#canvas"
    data-page="#page1"
></a>
```

and handling it on the click event:

```
$('.nav-toggle').click(function(e) {
    var sld = $(this).data('target');
    var page = $(this).data('page');
    if (sld.hasClass('in') && !sld.find(page).is(':visible')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }   
    sld.find('> *').hide();
    sld.find(page).show();
});
```